# Create pythonic variable if-else-structure

Tags: python, code-generation

I'm searching for a way to create variable if-elif-else-structures in python from a user input.
I have following example:

```
measVals = {'time': [400,500,...],'volt': [12.5,12.0,...], 'current': [500,350,...]}
```

Static if-elif-else structure:

```
if measVals['time'][0] <= 400 and measVals['volt'][0] > 8:
    if measVals['volt'][1] < 20:
        minMaxValues = {'current': {'min':0, 'max': 50}}
    elif measVals['volt'][1] < 12:
        minMaxValues = {'current': {'min':0, 'max': 100}}
elif measVals['time'][0] >= 500
    minMaxValues = {'current': {'min':0, 'max': 500}}
```

Now another user wants to define his own criteria and minMaxValues based on his measuring values,
so the structure of the if-elif-else could be completely different from mine.

My goal is to read in that data as argument of my code so i do not have to change the
code any time new criteria and so on were defined:

```
                                |   
                                | measVals
User defined criteria        ___V___        
------------------------->  |       |   
                            |       |
User defined minMaxValues   |  Code |
------------------------->  |       |   
                            |_______|
                                |
                                | correct minMaxValue dict
                                V
```

User measuring values:

```
measVals = {'time': [0,10,...],'temp': [23,23,...], 'pressure1': [500,350,...],'pressure2': [0,20,...]}
```

User defines criteria and corresponding min/max values (pseudo code):

```
    crit_1 = 'measVals['time'][0] <= 50' 
         .
         .
         .
    crit_1x = 'any condition' -> {'pressure1': {'max': 500,'min': 0},
                                  'pressure2': {'max': 50,'min': 0}}
    crit_2 = 'any condition' 
    crit = 'measVals['temp'][2] < 30'-> {'pressure1': {'max': 300, 'min': 0},
                                         'pressure2': {'max': 0,'min': 0}}
    crit_x = 'any condition'
         .
         .
         .
    crit_xx = 'any condition' -> {'pressure1': {'max': w, 'min': x},
                                  'pressure2': {'max': y,'min': z}}
```

So my idea was to read in (e.g. with a gui) user defined data as a nested dictionary with criteria as keys and minMaxValues on lowest level which looks like this:

```
criteriaMinMaxDict = 
{'measVals['time'][0] <= 50': {crit_1x: {'pressure1': {'max': 500,'min': 0},
                                         'pressure2': {'max': 50,'min': 0}}},
 crit_2: {'measVals['temp'][2] < 30': {'pressure1': {'max': 300, 'min': 0},
                                       'pressure2': {'max': 0,'min': 0}}},
 crit_x: {crit_xx: {'pressure1': {'max': w, 'min': x},
                    'pressure2': {'max': y,'min': z}}}}
```

With this dict i have to use eval(key) with combination of recursion to get the right minMaxValues.
This works but looks so wrong, especially the criteria string as keys.

Does someone have a better (more pythonic) way to solve this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you use `pprint.pprint` to display your dict? This is unreadable... Thanks

Comment: I meant to edit your question...

Comment: I wouldn't worry about being Pythonic.  I'd suggest that you get the code working any way you can, and then possibly think about ways to modify the code to make it simpler and more readable, and possibly more Pythonic.  Remember the famous saying "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." - Showing the forum a more complete program would certainly help us to help you get where you ultimately want to be.